# Continuity in the roots of an algebraic variety with respect to the coordinates

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, implicit-function-theorem

If I'm slightly misusing definitions forgive me I'm not an algebraist.

I have $N$ polynomials $f_n(x)$, $n=1,\ldots,N$ where $x\in \mathbb{R}^N$ and the set $\{x:f_n(x)=0\text{ for all }n\}$ is finite. If I slightly change the coordinates in the polynomials are there some conditions and a result that lets me ensure that the roots themselves change continuously?

As for the work I've done so far, I can apply the Implicit Function Theorem so that as long as the matrix $A_{ij}=\frac{d}{dx_j}f_i(x)$ is invertible at all roots I can ensure that the roots change continuously and there is no bifurcation. And in the complement of the neighbourhoods of these points, one of my polynomials is $x_1^2+\ldots+x_N^2=1$ so by compactness no other roots show up. But stitching these two results together is a pain and it seems likely that this is a standard result in a topic I'm not familiar with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, (real) solutions can just disappear under small perturbations, so you'd definitely have to assume that the number of solutions, counted appropriately, stays constant. But that's not enough either because you can move zeros around between factors. Consider for example
$$
x=a, \quad (x^2+y^2)(xy-1)=0 .
$$
For $a=0$, this is solved by $(0,0)$, but for small $a\not=0$, we obtain $(a,1/a)$ as the unique solution.

Comment: It could be argued perhaps that I in fact did not count appropriately here, but if that bothers you, then you can also square the factor $xy-1$.

Comment: I'm actually not concerned about solutions disappearing, for my problem all I want to know is that more don't show up.

Comment: @PepeSilvia: But they will, as the example shows if you remove the first factor in the second polynomial.

Comment: Ah, I see! I noticed you took advantage of constant terms here, does it make any difference if I'm in projective space? Say all terms of all polynomials are quadratic.

Comment: @PepeSilvia, note that you can always projectivise, replacing $(x^2 + y^2)(x y - 1)$ by $(x^2 + y^2)(x y - z^2)$.